# Refer/Import existing AutoScalingGroup Resource from CDK Stack

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to referring an existing AutoScalingGroup from my CodeDeploy with AutoScalingGroup.**from_auto_scaling_group_name** static method in order to integrate with CodePipeline for automating EC2/On-premise deployment. I have the following code snippet for your reference.

```
# Refer existing AutoScaling Group
asg_1 = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup.from_auto_scaling_group_name(self, "AutoScaleGroup", "WSAutoscaleStack-webServerAsgIdASG12345-XXXXXX")

# EC2 Deployment Groups
deployment_group = codedeploy.ServerDeploymentGroup(self, "CodeDeployDeploymentGroup", deployment_group_name="MyDeploymentGroup", install_agent=True, auto_scaling_groups=[asg_1])
```

After validating the stack with 'cdk ls', I got an error which says,

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot get policy fragment of AMIPipelineStack/AutoScaleGroup, resource imported without a role
```

As far as I understand, the referenced resource should be imported as an object, so that I can use it all dependents including iam.role from the resource. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the fromAutoScalingGroupName method doesn't "Import" the role ([see here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/77ce45d878f2d1cb453e36ae4d83228bee878ef1/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-autoscaling/lib/auto-scaling-group.ts#L836))

One option you have is to implement that import by yourself. The above linked Import class would then look like (in Typescript):

```
public static fromAutoScalingGroupNameWithRole(scope: Construct, id: string, autoScalingGroupName: string, roleArn:string): IAutoScalingGroup {
class ImportWithRole extends AutoScalingGroupBase {
  public autoScalingGroupName = autoScalingGroupName;
  public autoScalingGroupArn = Stack.of(this).formatArn({
    service: 'autoscaling',
    resource: 'autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName',
    resourceName: this.autoScalingGroupName,
  });
  public readonly osType = ec2.OperatingSystemType.UNKNOWN;
  public readonly grantPrincipal = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, `${id}-role`, roleArn)
}

return new ImportWithRole(scope, id);
```

}

Another maneuver you could do (if applicable to your use-case) is to **really** import the auto-scaling group and its role into the Cloudformation stack. The resources will then be managed with the CDK/Cloudformation stack and you could use the standard AutoScalingGroup constructor and provide your Role. The downside here is that it's currently quite a painful process (see [link](https://medium.com/@visya/how-to-import-existing-aws-resources-into-cdk-stack-f1cea491e9))

Comment: That's great point! I was stuck for a couple of days without any clues. Much appreciate your contribution. Let me take a look at my Python codes to see if I can implement "Import" the role and test it.