# How to import ECS instance as ALB Target

Tags: typescript, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have two separate typescript cdk stacks, one is an Application Load Balancer, and the other is serving as an standalone ec2 container based on a docker image. I would like for the ALB to route to the ec2 container instance but am having issues with referencing it as a target that is out of scope. In particular I would like the alb stack to import the ec2 container stack and target it from the listener, rather than the ec2 container stack requesting access from the alb stack.

The listener/addTargets on the alb stack accepts an array of multiple:

`Instance, IPAddress, or any self-registering load balancing target`

and calling `new targets.*` in that array (referenced as `import * as targets from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets';`) shows several options:

`AlbArnTarget, AlbTarget, InstanceIdTarget, InstanceTarget, IpTarget, LambdaTarget`

- `AlbArnTarget` and `AlbTarget` do not work because I cannot route from one alb to another, the property `attachToApplicationTargetGroup` is not present so  I suppose it is not a "self-registering load balancing target", only `attachToNetworkTargetGroup` is available, which makes sense from what I've seen- only a NLB can route to an ALB.
- `InstanceIdTarget`, `InstanceTarget` and `IpTarget` seem promising, but I cannot figure out how to export them from the ecs container stack and also import them into the alb stack. I would want to define an ssm parameter reference from the ecs container stack that has the the `InstanceId` or the `IpTarget` but cannot find in the constructs any generated `Instance`, `InstanceId` or `IpAddress` to define as an SSM parameter, and further I cannot figure out how to import any of the properties into the ALB CFN stack.

  - At a high level- in my ecs container stack, I have the vpc (fromLookup), a new cluster, an autoScalingGroup, a capacityProvider, a taskDefinition, a container, and the ec2Service- all interconnected. In all of these constructs I cannot find any reference to a generated instance, ip address, or instanceArn.
- Finally the `LambdaTarget` is irrelevant as I am wanting to point to the ecs container, which is not a lambda. However I do also have the ALB pointing to several lambdas in addition using this `LambdaTarget` pattern.
- It seems that the `AutoScalingGroup` as a target would be the way to go, because it has `attachToApplicationTargetGroup` but again this is only defined in the scope of the ecs container, if I import it into the ALB stack with `const asg = AutoScalingGroup.fromAutoScalingGroupName();`, the `attachToApplicationTargetGroup` is not defined.

I did find this SO but it seems a bit hacky, and getting into it, I start to copy the whole aws cdk library into my local code, as everything is interconnected.

[Refer/Import existing AutoScalingGroup Resource from CDK Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748035/refer-import-existing-autoscalinggroup-resource-from-cdk-stack)

Would appreciate any insight you might have, or alternatives. Again I'd like the ECS ec2/Container to be standalone and have the ALB stack route to it by importing it, and adding it as a target on the listener.

Answer (score 0):

With ECS you don't configure the ALB targets directly. You configure the ECS service with knowledge of the load balancer, and ECS automatically registers new instances of the service with the target group as it spins them up.

See the `service.registerLoadBalancerTargets()` example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html).

Comment: I found that I could have ecs create a target group and export the arn for it via ssm, and then import that in my separate alb as listener.addTargets/targetGroupName, running into issue where the ecs container won't complete deployment without a associated load balancer, so seems like a chicken/egg issue. I need the arn of the ecs container for the load balancer deployment, and I need the load balancer to successfully deploy the ecs container. I'm trying to deploy ecs container with a desiredCount/minHealthyPercent of 0, then change it later,but its hacky.WIll look at your solution next thanks

Comment: It's really strange to have two stacks for an ECS service and its load balancer. It's certainly not the standard setup for this type of configuration. The ECS service and the load balancer are usually tightly coupled. However I think you will find that you can create a load balancer and an **empty** target group without any references to the ECS service. Then in the ECS stack you just have to pass the service the reference to the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks, what I had in mind was a backend services load balancer that can route/proxy to standalone lambdas and ecs containers, that way those devs can deploy their updates separately, while using ssm to maintain a constant reference from the alb to those services. For the lambdas is easy since they are uncoupled naturally.

To your point I found this example link in the docs below the ```registerLoadBalancerTargets()``` example

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/cross-stack-load-balancer/split-at-targetgroup.ts

Comment: What is the 'networkType' for task ?  I want to use 'awsvpc' network. But, for task with 'awsvpc' network can be registered with Target Group of 'ip' type. Not sure how can we use both 'awsvpc' networking with AutoScalingGroup capacity provider ? (AutoScalingGroup expects target group type = INSTANCE).

Comment: @MandarK None of that matters, it works the same way regardless of network mode, since you just tell ECS what target group to use, and it handles the actual registration of tasks with the target group for you. And the AutoScalingGroup capacity provider is for underlying EC2 instances in the cluster, and has no relation to the ECS load balancer. If you are having problems then please post a separate question on this site.

Comment: Thanks Mark. In my case the trick was to remove the association between autoscaling group and the LB target group. Only register the ECS service as the target. Effectively, let ECS autoscale the ec2 instance capacity based on the task scheduling requirements.

I also ended up not specifying the target-type while registering an empty target group with LoadBalancer.